# Relationship between tables not showing in asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net, relational-database

I'm building a asp.net application. I have two classes a Film and a Direector class where I implemented a many to many reltionship.

Director Class

```
public class Director
{
    private ICollection<Film> _films;

    public Director()
    {
        _films = new List<Film>();
    }

    public int DirectorID { get; set; }

    public string fName { get; set; }

    public string lName { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Film> Films
    {
        get { return _films; }
        set { _films = value; }
    }
}
```

Film Class

```
public class Film
{
    private ICollection<Director> _directors;

    public Film()
    {
        _directors = new List<Director>();
    }

    public int FilmId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Minutes { get; set; }

    public string AgeClassification { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Director> Directors
    {
        get { return _directors; }
        set { _directors = value; }
    }
}
```

Seed Method

```
protected override void Seed(FilmNetwork.Models.FilmNetworkContext context)
    {

        var films = new List<Film>
            {
                new Film() { FilmId = 1, Name = "The Dark Knight", Minutes = 152, AgeClassification = "15A" },
                new Film() { FilmId = 2, Name = "The Social Network", Minutes = 120, AgeClassification = "15A" },
                new Film() { FilmId = 3, Name = "Up In The Air", Minutes = 109, AgeClassification = "15A" },
                new Film() { FilmId = 4, Name = "Slumdog Millionaire", Minutes = 120, AgeClassification = "15A" },
                new Film() { FilmId = 5, Name = "The Wolf Of Wall Street", Minutes = 180, AgeClassification = "18" },
                new Film() { FilmId = 6, Name = "King Kong", Minutes = 221, AgeClassification = "12" },
                new Film() { FilmId = 7, Name = "Schindler's List", Minutes = 195, AgeClassification = "18" }
            };
            films.ForEach(f => context.Films.AddOrUpdate(film => film.Name, f));
            context.SaveChanges();



        var directors = new List<Director>
            {
                new Director() { DirectorID = 1, fName = "Christopher", lName = "Nolan", Age = 46,
                    Films = films.Where(f => (f.Name == "The Dark Knight")).ToList()},
                new Director() { DirectorID = 2, fName = "David", lName = "Fincher", Age = 54,
                    Films = films.Where(f => (f.Name == "The Social Network")).ToList() },
                new Director() { DirectorID = 3, fName = "Jason", lName = "Reitman", Age = 39,
                    Films = films.Where(f => (f.Name == "Up In The Air")).ToList() },
                new Director() { DirectorID = 4, fName = "Danny", lName = "Boyle", Age = 60,
                    Films = films.Where(f => (f.Name == "Slumdog Millionaire")).ToList() },
                new Director() { DirectorID = 5, fName = "Martin", lName = "Scorsese", Age = 74,
                    Films = films.Where(f => (f.Name == "The Wolf Of Wall Street")).ToList() },
                new Director() { DirectorID = 6, fName = "Peter", lName = "Jackson", Age = 55,
                    Films = films.Where(f => (f.Name == "King Kong")).ToList() },
                new Director() { DirectorID = 7, fName = "Steven", lName = "Spielberg", Age = 70,
                    Films = films.Where(f => (f.Name == "Schindler's List")).ToList() },
            };
            directors.ForEach(d => context.Directors.AddOrUpdate(director => director.lName, d));
            context.SaveChanges();
```

I have an ajax search which producers films based a id. It returns the film, and directors with the director field is blank as for some reason the relationship isn't being implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add director here:

```
new Film() { FilmId = 1, Name = "The Dark Knight", Minutes = 152, AgeClassification = "15A"  }
```

Also do you absolutely need to have many to many relations? there aren't many cases when film has more then one director, so it would be more simple to add one to many relations.

How to implement one to many relations:

Director Class

```
public class Director
{



    public int DirectorID { get; set; }

    public string fName { get; set; }

    public string lName { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Film> Films{get;set;}

}
```

Film Class

```
public class Film
{



    public int FilmId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Minutes { get; set; }

    public string AgeClassification { get; set; }

    public virtual Director Director { get; set; }
}
```

Then just add it like this:

```
new Film() { FilmId = 1, Name = "The Dark Knight", Minutes = 152, AgeClassification = "15A" Director = _context.directors.where(x=> x.ID == "1"// or whichever parameter you want to find director from list)  }
```

Comment: I dont need a many to many, but i dont know how to implment a one to many :) :)